# Jenkins giving error "WorkflowScript: 3: Invalid agent type "docker" specified. Must be one of [any, label, none] @ line 3, column 9"

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I started to integrate Jenkins with Docker but getting the below error while running a pipeline job.

Error message:

> WorkflowScript: 3: Invalid agent type "docker" specified. Must be one of [any, label, none] @ line 3, column 9.

Installed Plugins:

1. Docker plugin
2. Docker pipeline

Pipeline snippet:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:latest'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage ('Check') {
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -v'
            }
        }
    }
}
```